# Mic-ing up solid electric guitar

Tags: guitar, microphones

I'm trying to experiment with a technique that I believe was used by Buddy Holly and perhaps other guitarists. That is mixing the guitar signal with a microphone signal from the guitar being recorded acoustically. With an admittedly crummy karaoke mic the sound is at a low level and a bit noisy when boosted.  Where is the best place to position the mic to get maximum signal (whilst still being practical to play - given I'm not going to play beyond the 12th fret)?

Comment: At or above the 12th fret, pointing towards your strumming hand will get you closest & pointing in the right direction, with least chance of hitting it.

Comment: Solid, Les Paul Studio

Comment: I've read a few apocryphal tales that the very quiet beginning of "Wish You Were Here" was an electric 12 string, intentionally unplugged. In any case, I think a better quality mic placed a few feet away will allow a better overall sound and easier playing access than a very low output one up close. I wouldn't worry about hand movement in front of the strings; in practice any variation might add to the rhythm in useful ways.

Comment: @Andy, I'm gonna presume you mean the song by Pink Floyd and not the one by Incubus.

Comment: @Dedwards yes you're right I meant the PF version :)

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting technique. I would presume that the optimal mic location would be smack dab in-between the neck and the neck pickup. You'll get a little bit of resonating from the body, and that creamy sweet spot on the strings.